# Query with window function over slightly different over clauses, remove table spool

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this query where I can't get the plan I am after.

My query looks like this:

Rows are put in different groups (partition by), from each group I want to pick one row, using row_number to assign a priority.
I also need a flag, which is an aggregate over all rows in each group.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT  [ProductReviewID]
        ,[ProductID]
        ,[ReviewerName]
        ,[ReviewDate]
        ,[Rating]
        ,[Comments]
        ,[ModifiedDate]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ProductID order by ReviewDate) as Prio
        ,min(rating) over (partition by ProductID) as Flag
    FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[ProductReview]
) x
WHERE Prio = 1 and Flag >= 2
```

The resulting plan looks like this (query1):
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auamqfb9LjGpaoxpkRpYS3iIVbE
The problem are the table spools.
The plan I want looks like Query2, where there is one sort the feeds into a window spool ( I cant show an exact plan, because I dont have a dev-server with sql2016).

`select ... <- window spool <- sort <- ...`
The problem arises because the optimizer is not smart enough to see that one sort (ProductId, ReviewDate) is good for both window functions.

I can get the plan I want, if make the over clause the same (this should give you a plan like just described):

```
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ProductID order by ReviewDate) as Prio
        ,min(rating) over (partition by ProductID  order by ReviewDate) as Flag
```

But that changes the result of `min()` in way that does not meet the required logic here.

Any ideas? Thanks for help.

**EDIT**: This is what I have with lptrs help, the trick is to put one "dummy" column as the first for order by. I regard it as answered. Thanks.

```
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ProductID order by ProductID, ReviewDate) as Prio
,min(rating) over (partition by ProductID  order by ProductID) as Flag
```

Comment: using `order by ReviewDate` is redundant for `MIN()` aggregation. No need to get such a performance loss.

Comment: I dont think so, but I also stumbled over this. You would expect this is the same (the minimum value of all rows with the same productId): `min(rating) over (partition by ProductID  order by ReviewDate)` vs. `min(rating) over (partition by ProductID  )`. But it is not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-producing-a-moving-average-and-cumulative-total

Comment: you could try "neutralizing" the effect of ReviewDate in the windowed min():  `min(rating) over (partition by ProductID  order by ReviewDate-ReviewDate)` that might prevent the lazy spool but it might not save the execution from an additional sort..

Comment: @lptr I think this works. If I add the "dummy columns" for both, I get one sort, a window spool and the results look good. Row_number over `(partition by ProductID  order by ReviewDate -  ReviewDate,  ReviewDate)`.  min over `(partition by ProductID  order by ReviewDate -  ReviewDate)`. Smart idea, thanks.